# Getting data from an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I am just learning knockout and I am facing a problem that I can not seem to understand.
I have this object:

```
    var studentPersonalDetails = ko.observable();
    var isInitialized = false;

    var vm = {
        //bindable
        title: ko.observable('Profile'),
        dataLoading: ko.observable(false),
        hasErrors: ko.observable(false),
        errorMessage: ko.observable(''),

        //data
        profileStudentPersonalDetails: studentPersonalDetails,      

        //operations
        activate: activate

    };

    return vm;
```

profileStudentPersonalDetails is the equivalent of this C# object from the server:

```
    public int? StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }     
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
```

And is populated from a service.My problem is that I do know how to access the data from this object so I can display it on a html view.

I have tryed this versions:

```
<strong data-bind="text: StudentNumber">
<strong data-bind="text: profileStudentPersonalDetails.StudentNumber">
```

But non seem to work.The data gets populated into the object the right way of that I am sure and I am able to acces the other fields from the data for example the title:

```
<strong data-bind="text: title">
```

And this works.

How can I access the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
profileStudentPersonalDetails().StudentNumber
```

observables are functions.  To get the objects they represent, you need to call the function.  You can then access the property off the result of the function.